# Wordpress invalid argument supplied for foreach

Tags: wordpress

Hello here is my website i receive this error on my header [site](https://kastratihome.com)

error code :

> Warning
>   : Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /home/enghouse/kastratihome.com/wp-content/themes/funiter/framework/includes/theme-functions.php
>   on line
>   828

My code :

```
823    if ( $funiter_enable_vertical == 1 ) :
824     $locations = get_nav_menu_locations();
825     $menu_id             = $locations['vertical_menu'];
826     $menu_items          = wp_get_nav_menu_items( $menu_id );
827     $count               = 0;
828     foreach ( $menu_items as $menu_item ) {
829         if ( $menu_item->menu_item_parent == 0 ) {
830             $count ++;
831         }
832     }
```

Here is the code please help me with it...

Answer (score 0):

```
try{
    /* [ your iteration on header.php, line 828, likely something that looks like foreach($foo as $f) { ... } */
}
catch(Exception $e){
    /* technically, you don't need to do anything here unless it serves you */
    /* but it's common to log an error or return a value */
}
```

Comment: Can u define a litle bit more , i have to add this in function.php or ??

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that you are passingan array to foreach using the is_array function.

If you are not sure whether you're going to pass an array or not, then you can change your code like the following.
If you are not sure it's going to be an array you can always check using the following PHP example code:

```
if(is_array($value) || is_object($value)){
  foreach ($variable as $item) {
   //do something
  }
}
```

Check your foreach() in /home/enghouse/kastratihome.com/wp-content/themes/funiter/framework/includes/theme-functions.php and make sure you check whether it is an array before using foreach().